# Slide show javascript error

Tags: javascript, types, styles

I am using a script from the WOW Slider (free version) which is as follows:

```
    var slideIndex = 0;
    function showSlides() {
        var i;
        slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); 
        dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
    showSlides();
```

It seems to work OK, however when I do an SEO check on the page it says there is a Javascript error in the line:

```
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
```

The specific message is:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".

This seems to be saying that `slides` is undefined, but it appears to be defined in the variable declarations.

I'm a bit of a beginner with Javascript and would therefore appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think showSlides method is called before your html list 'mySlides' is loaded. Call showSlides method from in window.onload.

Comment: Could you also support html sample?

Comment: I run your code as exactly you wrote with 4 divs class mySlides and 4 divs class dot and I don't have any error in my console

Comment: It is not `slides` which is undefined, but `slides[slideIndex-1]`. What is `slides.length` value? Why is `slideIndex` out of the function?
How often is invoked `showSlides()`?

Comment: Yes, it seems to run without errors, I was only concerned because when testing the page in an on page SEO checker it identifies this javascript "Uncaught TypeError" and really wasn't sure what it was referring to.

Comment: I moved the showSlides() to after the function as it was previously shown as the first statement, but the on page seo checker identified this as an error saying it was being used before it was declared.

Comment: "I think showSlides method is called before your html list 'mySlides' is loaded. Call showSlides method from in window.onload. – Volkan Akın Paşa "

I think this may be on the right track. If the method is being called before the page is fully loaded then the slides wouldn't be defined? Is that right?

Comment: I should also mention that the script is positioned at the end of the HTML body (this was where the "instructions" for WOW Slider said to put it. But again, perhaps as the page isn't complete at the point the slides are not fully defined? The main question of course is if there IS a fault, then why does it work fine!?

Comment: I think @laruiss is correct, your answer "i removed the line in question and the one that follows it" accepts that, since the only thing common between the 2 lines is the `slideIndex` variable, this means that `slides[0]` must not exist (`slides` is an empty array).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I have resolved the problem by commenting out two lines of code. First I took out the line in question! When I checked all the style sheets, etc., there was no class identified as "MySlides", so I thought this is why the error message was being generated. After I took that line out the error message then refereed to the next line, which I also took out, then, with no errors being generated the slide show still works perfectly in every way! So, perhaps these were two lines of redundant code accidentally left in by the original programmer! I have to admit that I can't see how it works, but it does!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<body onload="showSlides()">
```

removing from second line on JS: `showSlides()`

Comment: Inline handlers are *very* bad practice nowadays - they're not something to be recommended.